# How to set default quantity of queries in Elasticsearch with NEST in .NET 5.0?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, .net-5

I'm working with **NEST** in **.NET 5.0** and currently every query always returns a maximum of 10 records, for example, the code below always returns 10 records, and in this index I have more than 100 records.

```
var listaData = await _repositoryProcessResumeElastic.SearchAsync(descriptor => descriptor.MatchAll());
```

[image]

How do I configure in NEST to set a total default value of records in the query without having to use `.Size`?

Comment: This property is not configurable https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/23861 . You will have to pass it in size parameter in query

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not want use .size?